# javax.script - rhino - how can view or edit native functions?

Tags: java, rhino, javax.script

I want to implement a function that is similar to JSON.stringify.

When I call:

```
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    Object eval = engine.eval("JSON.stringify");
    System.out.println(eval);
```

I get **sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.IdFunctionObject**.
But how can I really view how is it implemented ?
Can I edit or add such "native" functions ?

Don't offer to implement **sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Function** - I know this ability, but want gain some knowledge about how native functions work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't eval **JSON.stringify** because it's not implemented in Rhino. (It's mostly a browser based thing, although I guess Nashorn and node do have it).

You can eval the contents of [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which implements JSON.stringify and then your code should work.

But if you just want to stringify, then I would use **org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJSON.stringify**.

Comment: Try this code and you see that it is implemented: **new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript").eval("JSON.stringify({x:1})");**

Comment: I dunno. It does not work for me, but it could be on account of an earlier version. My ScriptEngineFactory reports version **1.6 release 2**, but executing your code throws an exception:  *javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "JSON" is not defined*.